# WPF, Binding Programmatically an item of a Observable collection of list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `ObservableCollection<List<MessageView>>` (MessageView is a custom class) I instantiate it that way

```
public ObservableCollection<List<MessageView>> _messagesView;
public ObservableCollection<List<MessageView>> messagesView {
    get {
        if (_messagesView == null) {
            _messagesView = new ObservableCollection<List<MessageView>>();
        }
        return _messagesView;
    }
    set {
        if (_messagesView != value) {
            _messagesView = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(messagesView)));
        }
    }
}
```

This property is set on a Singleton

I want to bind one of the item collection to a datagrid it would look that way in xaml:

```
<xmlns:module="clr-namespace:Myproject.MyNameSpace;assembly=Myproject">
<DataGrid 
    Name="DataGrid_messages"
    ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding messagesView[2], Source={x:Static module:Singleton.Instance}}"
>
```

This is working well that way but this is not what I want to do. I want to have the control of my index. So I have to do the binding in c# with my controller but I never found an example to bind with a special index.

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("messagesView");
myBinding.Source = Singleton.Instance;
myBinding.Path = ??
DataGrid_messages.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

Share your thought about this, is it possible? Or a better way to do it?

**UPDATE**

Additional change to do with Clemens Answer:

The binding is set with the internal list so it's it which should be ObservableCollection type:

```
public List<ObservableCollection<MessageView>> messagesView;
```

Comment: It the index is fixed, `myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("messagesView[{0}]", index));` should work.

Comment: @Clemens I see. thanks for the information.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks it's working well! But now I have an exeption each time i change the property `An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source` I tried to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on my bindings and checked if I modify my list on the UI thread but it's still not working

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect on a one-way binding, and a binding to the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl is always one-way.

Comment: @Clemens Hum okay but adding `myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;` shouldn't do the trick so?

Comment: Why that, the binding is one-way by default. No need to set that.

Comment: @Clemens Ok my bad I just had to change my list to ObservableCollection since I'm using the list inside my ObservableCollection in my view, I think I can even invert my two collections `List<ObservableCollection<MessageView>> messagesView`

Comment: @Clemens It's sad that you comment instead of answer I will do a clear answer to close this Question topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the index is fixed, creating the binding path in code behind could look like this:

```
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("messagesView[{0}]", index));
```